How do I perform maths with counted values when using left joins?
Hopefully someone can help me here.
Effectively I am trying to count three different types of possible registration entry for students for a given day, and then perform maths using those counted values.
So far my SQL is as follows:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.txtFullName, dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID
    FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils
    where dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.intSystemStatus = 1
) as PupDetails

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtRegistrationStatus) as presCount,
        dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtSchoolID
    FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance

    WHERE dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Present'
      AND dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
    GROUP BY
        dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtSchoolID 
) as Present

  ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Present.txtSchoolID

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtRegistrationStatus) as absentCount,
        dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtSchoolID
    FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance

    WHERE dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Absent'
      AND dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
    GROUP BY
        dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtSchoolID
) as Absent

    ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Absent.txtSchoolID

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtRegistrationStatus) as notRegCount,
        dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtSchoolID
    FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance

    WHERE dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Not Registered'
      AND dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
    GROUP BY
        dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance.txtSchoolID
) as NotReg

    ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Absent.txtSchoolID

ORDER BY
    PupDetails.txtFullName

This gives me a list of all pupils, and how many absent, present, and not registered entries they have for the given day. So far so good.
But what I can't figure out is how to then do maths using the count values. For example, how might I divide the number of present entries by the number of absent entries?

Your database hase a very bad case of Hungarian-naming - you should fix that...

Also, your SQL is near-impossible to read because you're using the fully-qualified table-name for every column. Please edit your SQL to use a succint alias instead...

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance, with an emphasis on minimal.

You can include mathematical operations in sql. You can assign selected values to variables and perform mathematical operations with these, depending on the environment you're running the SQL in.

Please tag your request with your DBMS, so we see what SQL features are available.

For a start, you can significantly simplify this query by using conditional aggrgeation instead of duplicate joins. Then you can just do the maths on the outside of the subquery.
Also:

Null out zero divisors using NULLIF.
Use short table aliases, to make your query readable.
Use a deterministic date format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

SELECT
    p.txtFullName,
    p.txtSchoolID,
    counts.*,
    presCount * 1.0 / NULLIF(absentCount, 0) AS SomePercentage
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sra.txtSchoolID,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN sra.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Present'        THEN 1 END) as presCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN sra.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Absent'         THEN 1 END) as absentCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN sra.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Not Registered' THEN 1 END) as notRegCount
    FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance sra
    WHERE sra.dtRegistrationDateTime > '2024-12-03 08:25:00'
      AND sra.dtRegistrationDateTime < '2024-12-03 16:00:00'
    GROUP BY
        sra.txtSchoolID 
) as counts ON counts.txtSchoolID = p.txtSchoolID
WHERE p.intSystemStatus = 1
ORDER BY
    PupDetails.txtFullName


Your question is not entirely clear - what kind of difficulty are you experiencing.
To begin with, you can rewrite the request in this form, using table aliases.
SELECT dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.txtFullName
  , dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils as PupDetails

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(VwRSRA.txtRegistrationStatus) as presCount
    ,VwRSRA.txtSchoolID
  FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance as VwRSRA
  WHERE VwRSRA.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Present'
    AND  dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' 
    AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
  GROUP BY VwRSRA.txtSchoolID 
) as Present ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Present.txtSchoolID

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(VwRSRA.txtRegistrationStatus) as absentCount
    ,VwRSRA.txtSchoolID
  FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance VwRSRA
  WHERE VwRSRA.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Absent'
    AND  dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' 
    AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
  GROUP BY VwRSRA.txtSchoolID 
) as Absent ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Absent.txtSchoolID

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(VwRSRA.txtRegistrationStatus) as notRegCount
    ,VwRSRA.txtSchoolID
  FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance VwRSRA
  WHERE VwRSRA.txtRegistrationStatus = 'Not Registered'
    AND  dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' 
    AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
  GROUP BY VwRSRA.txtSchoolID 
) as NotReg  ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Absent.txtSchoolID

WHERE PupDetails.intSystemStatus = 1
ORDER BY PupDetails.txtFullName

Your query will be more understandable in this form.
You can calculate the number of statuses in a single request.
SELECT dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.txtFullName
  , dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID
    -- your math
  ,case when totalCount>0 then presCount/totalCount elese null end presPct
  ,case when totalCount>0 then absentCount/totalCount elese null end absentPct
  ,case when totalCount>0 then notRegCount/totalCount elese null end notRegPct
FROM dbo.TblPupilManagementPupils as PupDetails

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT VwRSRA.txtSchoolID
    ,sum(case when txtRegistrationStatus = 'Present' then 1 else 0 end) as presCount
    ,sum(case when txtRegistrationStatus = 'Absent' then 1 else 0 end) as absentCount
    ,sum(case when txtRegistrationStatus = 'Not Registered' then 1 else 0 end) as notRegCount
    ,count(*) as totalCount
  FROM dbo.VwRegistrationSchoolRegistrationAttendance as VwRSRA
  WHERE 
        dtRegistrationDateTime > '03-12-2024 08:25:00' 
    AND dtRegistrationDateTime <  '03-12-2024 16:00:00'
  GROUP BY VwRSRA.txtSchoolID 
) as Counters ON PupDetails.txtSchoolID = Counters.txtSchoolID

WHERE PupDetails.intSystemStatus = 1
ORDER BY PupDetails.txtFullName

